# How to set up two SSH keys for two GitLab accounts and push/pull by using TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, ssh, key, gitlab, tortoisegit

Currently I'm using GitLab as my remote GIT server.
I have no problem using single Gitlab account with SSH key assigned to it.

But now I applied another Gitlab account and I'm trying to use the same SSH key for it, but I cannot add the key to this new account.
The error is as follows when I tried to add the key:

> Key has already been taken
>   Fingerprint has already been taken

So how should I use the same key to access the second Gitlab account? 
if it is not possible, how should I use two keys at the same time.

By the way, I'm using windows system.

Thanks in advance!!

**Updates**

Below is my config file. And it is as follows:

```
#my primary account
Host {account1}
    User git
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa1

#for NPR_HPTG account
Host {account2}
    User git
    HostName gitlab.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

And I'm having two Gitlab account,

```
git@gitlab.com:{account_1}/repo1.git
git@gitlab.com:{account_2}/repo1.git
```

Still, I cannot access to the `account_2`.

Previously, before I'm having this 2nd GitLab account, I simply upload the `ssh` key to the `account1` without needing set [This](https://coderwall.com/p/7smjkq/multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-accounts-on-github-or-gitlab). But now by following this, still, in the end I could push to the `git@gitlab.com:{account_2}/repo1.git`. And I'm using `TortoiseGit` to push/pull.

Comment: I think this is one of the cleanest solution- https://stackoverflow.com/a/52816828/515976

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Simply declare each private ssh keys in a `%HOME%/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host gitlabuser1
    User git
    Hostname {hostname}
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa1

Host gitlabuser2
    User git
    Hostname {hostname}
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

That supposes your set of ssh keys are:

```
%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa1 ; %HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa1.pub
%HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa2 ; %HOME%/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub
```

You can then use the urls for clone/push/pull:

```
gitlabuser1:yourRepo1
gitlabuser2:yourRepo2
```

Make sure your `CMD` session has `%HOME%` defined, usually to `%USERPROFILE%` (which is done for you with [`git-cmd.bat`](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/blob/master/git-cmd.bat))

You have a more detailed procedure [in this blog post](https://coderwall.com/p/7smjkq/multiple-ssh-keys-for-different-accounts-on-github-or-gitlab).

Comment: I'm inclined to beleive that merely writing `IdentityFile id_rsa2` should pick that `id_rsa2` file from `~/.ssh/` thus doing the Right Thing automagically. I'd try and see.

Comment: What should be the correct format for hte `gitlabuser1`. is it something like this: `git@gitlab.com:my_username`?

Comment: @GordonQu `gitlabuser1` is there to replace `git@gilab.com`. Note that with ssh url, the `username` is *never* part of the url, since it is the job of the public ssh key to authenticate you on the GitLab server side.

Comment: So how about the `{hostname}`, is it also the same, it should be `git@gitlab.com` as well?

Comment: @GordonQu `{hostname}` is to be replaced by the hostname of your gitlab server. If it is gitlab.com, then it would be replaced by `gitlab.com`

Comment: @GordonQu `Host git@gitlab.com` is incorrect: this is supposed to be a key, like `gitlabuser1` or `gitlabuser1`. The user must be specified with `User git` within the `Host gitlabuser1` section.

Comment: @GordonQu Fix the `Host` value, and add `User git`.

Comment: @GordonQu if you use `Host {account2}`, then the url to use would be `{account_2}:{account_2}/repo1.git`. Forget about `git@gitlab.com`. `Host` is a *key*. If you had set `Host` to `xxx2`, then the url would be `xxx2:{account2}/repo1.git`.