# Gitlab: can't SSH from home (Windows)

Tags: ssh, gitlab, vpn

I can't get SSH to work for GitLab from my home PC.

To be clear:
1. SSH works fine for BitBucket on the same machine
2. SSH key has been added and is correct
3. I'm connected through a VPN (working)

I get the following output when I try to connect with -v -v -v parameters:

```
$ ssh git@[server] -v -v -v
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/[me]/.ssh/config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [server] [ip] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [server] port 22: Attempt to connect timed ` out wssh: connect to host [server] port 22: Bad file number
```

Would this likely be a server configuration issue?

Edit:

I generated a new key and configured ssh to use it.
Here's the output:

```
$ ssh -Tvv git@[server]
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1i 6 Aug 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/[me].ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/[me]/.ssh/config line 5: Applying options for [server]
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to [server] [IP] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [IP] port 22: Attempt to connect timed out without establishing a connection
ssh: connect to host [server] port 22: Bad file number
```

Answer (score 1):

> SSH works fine for BitBucket on the same machine
>   SSH key has been added and is correct

I hope it isn't the *same* ssh key which has been added to GitLab, but a different public one (for a corresponding *different private* ssh key)

In that case, you would need an ~/.sssh/config referencing both public keys, as in "[How to set up two SSH keys for two GitLab accounts and push/pull by using TortoiseGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30320641/6309)":

```
# my primary account for BitBucket
Host bitbucket
    User git
    HostName bitbucket.com
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa1

# for GitLab server
Host gserver
    User git
    HostName {server}
    PreferredAuthentications publickey
    IdentityFile C:/Users/{username}/.ssh/id_rsa2
```

In the meantime, check the output of:

```
ssh -Tvv gserver
```

(with '`gserver`' being the entry of the `.ssh/config` file, which references the right private ssh key, and the user '`git`')

Comment: Updated my post because I can't use code in replies, no dice yet.

Comment: @ReinierKaper if you want your ssh/config to be used, you need to test with the Host entries, like `ssh -Tvv gserver`. Or the right key won't be used. I have edited my answer accordingly.