# Can't clone gitlab's repo via ssh after update

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

I have 2 gitlab servers.

Old gitlab version is 8.17...

New gitlab version is 11.0...

The servers has same users and same private keys.

I can't clone repo from new gitlab via ssh.
If I try to clone repo from the new gitlab host-machine it works. But if I forward my ssh key to another(any) machine I can to clone repo from the old gitlab server and can't clone it from the new gitlab server.

ssh-forwarding works correctly.

Anybody knows what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Simply try and generate a new set of keys, in order to register a new public key on the new server.

From there, use a `~/.ssh/config` file in order to reference the second private key, as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30961470/6309).