# Pod Install doesn't have access to private repo but git clone, etc. work on the same repo

Tags: ios, git, github, cocoapods

We have a project that has a private repo. I have access to this repo as I can `git clone`, etc. for that repo.

However, `pod install` on this same repo always asks for my login credentials,  getting the following message:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/TEAM/Pod.git/'
```

I am using an ssh connection. I wouldn't think that the issue is related to this as, like I mentioned, I can clone/pull/etc. successfully.

It is also worth noting that two other's on the team are able to `pod install` and `pod update` without any issues.

I've also wiped my credential-osxkeychain.

Thoughts? I'm running out of ideas.

---

Added details:

I can pod install in the Podfile, but this is for a Cocoapod we are creating, and the pod I'm having issues with is a dependency for this pod. Therefore in the Podfile we have put

```
#source 'https://github.com/TEAM/PodSpecs.git'
#source 'git@github.com:TEAM/PodSpecs.git'
```

where only one of those is uncommented (but neither work for me -- though both work for them).

And then in the Podspec we have

```
s.source = { :git => 'https://github.com/TEAM/PodSpecs.git'}
```

We have even tried:

```
s.source = { :git => 'git@github.com:TEAM/PodSpecs.git'}
```

I have also done the following command and verified the existence of the repo in `./cocoapods/repos`:

```
pod repo add Pod git@github.com:TEAM/PodSpecs.git
```

Comment: Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found/37814228. There are couple of solutions, it might help you.

Comment: Thanks @Sateesh for the suggestion. Sadly none of the solutions are working for me in there.

Answer (score 13):

In your `Podfile` instead of pointing to your private github repository via the `https` protocol use the `git` one:

```
pod 'MyPrivatePod', :git => git@github.com:<username>/myprivatepod.git
```

To avoid to type your password of your private key each time, be sure you've added it to your opened session. If you are on MacOS:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh.id_rsa
```

Comment: Sorry, I've now added more description. The first line of code could get the pod installed. However this is for a Pod that we ourselves are creating and so needs to be provided in the PodSpec as a source, or the linter will not be able to find the repo. Sorry for not including these details initially.


And the proper id_rsa file has been added since `git clone` etc. work -- unless there is a way to specify to Cocoapods specifically what to use (outside of credentials-osxkeychain, that is)?

Comment: I've updated the description now to include that information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue, when I started using new laptop. I could do the git clone for repo but pod install and pod update were not working for Cocoapod repo we created.

doing following this worked for me:

1. generating new ssh key for new laptop.
   https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
2. adding newly generated ssh key to GitHub.
   https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account