# Git - can't push after interactive rebase

Tags: git, github, version-control, git-merge, git-push

I have a `develop`  branch and a `feature` branch. I did some commits to develop branch after I created the feature branch from the develop branch. And also did some commits to feature branch. So the current situation is like this

```
A--B--C-----F--G (develop)
       \
        D--E (feature)
```

Then did a interactive rebase to feature branch and squash commits to single commit.

Then I tried to push the feature branch with `git push -f` and `git push origin --force` but it ended up with getting a error `remote: Repository not found.`

**what I want to do here is merge the changes of feature branch to develop without effecting changes done in develop branch.**

Have I done any wrong thing here or are there any better way to achieve my goal?

Comment: Try this first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047420/14104186. If not, check to see the remote is correct

Comment: By "Repository not found", there might be a spelling mistake in `git config remote.origin.url`. It's also possible that `git push` is using an username which does not have access to the repository.

Comment: @ElpieKay remote origin url is set to `https://github.com/myRepo/web.git`

Comment: The rebase did not cause the problem here. "Repository not found" indicates either that the repository really isn't there (possible but unlikely since you have checked) or that for some reason you no longer have permission to write to it or even to tell that it is there (likely, if you're using http or https, as GitHub are moving towards requiring ssh access, and will be turning off https write permission site-wide occasionally to prod people to move to ssh).

Comment: Please execute `git remote -v` to verify the url of remote, and make sure the remote repository exists and you have permission to access it.