# How to push or clone GitHub private repo

Tags: github

I am junior developer, just started my first job on company.

My question is,

I created new GitHub account for company and I joined company organization.

Now I have to push some works that I have done, but I having some problem.

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/company/navigator2.0_demo.git/' not found
```

I used another GitHub on my MacBook, should I do logout and re login something like this ??

Also I am trying to clone some repo, It shows me same error.

I will wait for your help. Thanks.

Comment: Please check in the below solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong , you need to use the same account you created for your company . In that same account , you can invite yourself as a collaborator. But it is advisable that you use your githubs company account .