# Repo cloned with GitHub Desktop cannot find private repo from terminal

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

I am using GitHub Desktop to clone repos because of the whole terminal auth deprecation. Usually when I clone a repo using GitHub Desktop, I am able to run the usual git commands from the terminal in VSCode. However this time, for some unknown reason, I cannot.

For example, I get the error:

```
~/repos/my-repo (main) $ git pull
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/my-repo.git/' not found
```

What do I have to do to get the auth working in the terminal?

I am signed in on both browser and GitHub Desktop in the correct account btw.

Comment: What do you get when you give `git remote -v`?

Comment: `origin  https://github.com/myUsername/my-repo.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/myUsername/my-repo.git (push)`

Answer (score 0):

I did some digging and found out that it's due to having old session states. To solve it, you need to remove all `github.com` credentials from the system.

For [Windows](https://github.community/t/git-clone-is-not-working-for-a-private-repo/501/4) (especially 10):

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Select 'User Accounts'.
3. Select 'Credential Manager'.
4. Delete all the `github.com` or `git` credentials from Web (if there is) and Windows Credentials.

For [Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53047420/15406141):

1. Open Keychain Access.
2. Delete the `github.com` password.

Comment: I deleted all my GitHub passwords from keychain. Issue persists.

Comment: @abc Hmm, how about removing the origin and re-adding it? `git remote remove origin` and then `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/myUsername/my-repo.git`

Comment: issue persists. Also I had to use `git remote add origin https://github.com/... .git` instead