# Remote: Repository not found but Error: remote origin already exists

Tags: git, github, git-push

I am all of a sudden having trouble doing a push (i.e. `git push origin master`). When I do I get prompted for my personal access token which is not expired (I double checked). Once I log in, then I get the error:

`remote: Repository not found`

`fatal: repository 'https://github.com/username/repo-name/' not found`

I tried `git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repo-name` which produced no errors but when I try the push again it the same thing as above happens.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: To add to it, I did `git remote add origin git@github.com:username/repo-name.git` and it gives me: `error: remote origin already exists`

Comment: What happens when you open the https URL in a browser?

Comment: It brings me directly to my repo

Comment: I have also tried removing the origin (i.e. `git remote rm origin`) and then adding it back in but still getting the same original  `Repository not found` issue

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer:
[Git - remote: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found)

I needed to check the `write:packages`. I forgot to do that when I created my new PAT.

Comment: then you shouldn't make that an answer. Your question is a duplicate. When users pollute stack overflow with duplicate questions, it make it harder for people to find existing answers to their questions. You should always exhaust existing questions before adding a new one.