# Git Issue with Repository not Found

Tags: git

When I try to push my changes, I get this error. Is there any way that I can remove these changes to not mess with my push, without reverting the file back.

[image]

In the image below, whenever I press the sync changes button, I get the error on the right

Comment: do you have commit access to the remote repo? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found

Comment: what do you mean by commit access?

Comment: Well that belief is incorrect.