# GitHub Desktop vs Bit bash new branch upload

Tags: git, github, github-desktop

I cannot understand why I am not able to upload a new branch called feature2 to GitHub from my local repo using Git bash.

I write
*git push -u origin feature2* and
I receive this message in the console:
*remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/mygithub/test3.git/' not found*

Using GitHub desktop I have no problems to upload the new branch (I have tried it before with another branch)
I use a Windows PC.

Comment: It turns out that I've resolved the issue like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56598802/11463971   The question is: why GitHub Desktop was working while git bash wasn't working properly?

Comment: Command-line Git and GitHub Desktop are using different credential methods. Why *that* is would likely be "because GitHub Desktop is written by different people who had different ideas about how to do that".