# git remote repo not found after installing Github Desktop on mac

Tags: git, macos, github, apple-m1, github-desktop

**After installing Gihhub Desktop** on my M1 mac, when i try to use git with anything else (VSCode , ITerm, Warp) i get this error:

[image]

Pulling, cloning, any external actions now only works with freaking Github Desktop.

I tried uninstalling it, but doesn't help.
**I tried** deleting keychain password from github, like suggested here [Git - remote: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found), but there are 2 that i can't delete (nothing happens when i click delete) and it doesn't help.

[image]

Any suggestion is welcome, thanks!