# Cannot sync, publish or push to github from VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, github

I cannot push any changes to Github via VS Code.  Any method I try ends with

`Git: remote: Repository not found.`

I've been through all similar issues and no proposed solution works.  If I go to Github Desktop, or just Git command line it works, but it does not work through VS Code.  That is, Sync Changes, Publish Branch, git push, etc., all fail with that error.  Using the same repositories, all of this is successful at my work computer, but not my home computer, so I must have configured something improperly.  Frustratingly, when I uninstalled and reinstalled it magically seemed to remember all of my previous settings.  Appreciate any help.  :-)

I've seen this:  [Git - remote: Repository not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37813568/git-remote-repository-not-found)
As well as several blogs about how to solve this.[image]

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the solution.  My VS Code seemed to have been confused by me logging into it multiple ways.  The thing that allowed me to reset everything was opening the credential manager and deleting everything that had to do with git or github.  When I thoroughly scrubbed it, my VS Code interface let me log in again, came up with the correct repositories, and lets me update again in both directions.
I actually found this answer on StackOverflow, so then I tried to delete this question, as it had no answers or comments.  Evidently that's no longer allowed.